# React Native Paper Button icon size

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hey is there a way to set the size of my Button Icon?

```
<Button
  contentStyle={[accordionStyles.header__button, ]}
  icon={show === Props.value ? "chevron-up" : "chevron-down"}
  direction='rtl'
  color='black'
>
...
</Button>
```

But if i try to size the Button with `size={40}` it's not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do by adding icons as a child, still that feature is not yet developed, they have raised a PR:

```
 import { Button, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<Button
  style={buttonStyle}
  mode="contained"
  contentStyle={buttonContentStyle}
>
  <Icon name="warning" size={24} color="#fff" />
  <View style={{ width: 16, height: 1 }} />
  <Text style={buttonTextStyle}>Hello World</Text>
</Button>
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: its just resizing my button and not the icon

Comment: @MrTilllus does it help?

Comment: Link to source of the code would have been nice: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1317#issuecomment-557903348

Answer (score 10):

For someone who is still stuck on this issue, I found this solution which works:

```
<Button
  mode="outlined"
  labelStyle={{ fontSize: 25 }}
  onPress={() => doSomething()}
  icon="share"
>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>My Text</Text>
</Button>
```

Wrap the text in `<Text>` component & give it a font size while the `labelStyle` will increase the size for the icon only

Comment: Great solution. Thanks Arun.

Answer (score 9):

All the provided solutions are jugar that's why I am answering this

```
<Button 
    icon={({ size, color }) => (
        <Icon name="location" size={20} color="#000" />
    )}
    mode="outlined" 
    onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
    contentStyle={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}
    style={{borderColor:"#000",borderWidth:2}}
>
    Details
</Button>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the Button labelStyle prop?

```
<Button
    labelStyle={{ fontSize: 24 }}
    icon="repeat"
    mode="text"
  >
    my button
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and achieve what I wanted to hope this will help someone in the future...

```
  import { Button } from "react-native-paper";
import PlusIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
 <View style={styles.button}>
    <Button uppercase={false} color="#FFFFFF" style={styles.button}>
      Add New Booking
    </Button>
    <View style={{ paddingLeft: "auto", right: -75 }}>
      <PlusIcon size={32} color={"#fff"} name={"pluscircle"} />
    </View>
  </View>


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
button: {
width: 208,
height: 52,
 alignItems: "center",  
justifyContent: "center",
borderRadius: 30,
backgroundColor: "#94C100",
position: "absolute",
bottom: 0,
right: 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In "react-native-paper": "^5.11.1":

```
import { Button, Icon } from 'react-native-paper';
...

<Button
   contentStyle={[accordionStyles.header__button, ]}
   icon={({ size, color }) => (
      <Icon source={show === Props.value ? "chevron-up" : "chevron-down"} size={50} color={color} />
   )}
   direction='rtl'
   color='black'
>

...
</Button>
```